# Qt - detect when all widgets have finished resizing for the first time

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to detect when all widgets in a QDialog (with a layout on it) have been resized?

I have an expensive operation to perform according to a widget's width. The problem is that when I start the QDialog window, the widget's width is 90, then after a while (after the resize has been done supposedly), the width goes to 700 (the size I see it on the screen).

So the question, again, is: is there a way/an event that gets fired when all widgets have been resized for the first time?

Comment: I suppose you could use a singleshot timer, or `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` with a queued connection, in the `QWidget::showEvent` when your dialog is shown for the 1st time.

Comment: I had this same problem once before. I just sub class from QWidget and emitted a signal from `showEvent` to notify others about its new geometry.

Comment: I had such problems before and realized it was only a problem in my debug build and the resizing was actually really fast in release. In such case I could ignore the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to subclass `QDialog` and override the `virtual void resizeEvent( QResizeEvent* event )` function. Like this:

```
// protected override
void MyDialog::resizeEvent( QResizeEvent* event )
{
    QDialog::resizeEvent( event );

    // Check the size of dialog at this point. Or define a signal and emit from here.
}
```